# Can we assign mutiple roles to multiple resources in Azure?

Tags: azure, powershell

I've been trying to use PowerShell code to assign multiple roles on multiple resources in Azure, The reason is that we dont use custome roles for cost, below is how i tried to write the code.

```
$RGs = Import-CSV -Path "C:\input\RBAC-RGs.csv"
$Roles = Import-CSV -Path "C:\input\RBAC-Roles.csv"

$AZAD = Get-AzADGroup -SearchString "Group-Name" #Get Group name Object ID
ForEach ($Group in $RGs) {
Get-AzResourceGroup -Name "$RGs.ResouceGroups" #Get Resource Group resource ID for scope
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId "$AZAD.id" `
-RoleDefinitionName "Storage Account Contributor" `
-Scope "/subscriptions/{subscripotionid}/resourceGroups/resource-group-name"
```

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. Where do you need help?

Comment: The code outcome is throwing this error
New-AzRoleAssignment : The Principal ID 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.PSADGroup.id' is not valid. Principal ID must be a GUID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible. You just have  a PowerShell issue within your script:

`New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId "$AZAD.id"` => You have to either omit the quotes here or wrap the property access like this: `"$($AZAD.id)"`.